# Increase spacing in table of contents only for specific portion

Tags: table-of-contents, width, section-titles

I have a text with some chapters, then all the indices and afterwards the appendices. When I just print the table of contents in the beginning, the heading of the appendix is too long and it overlaps the title as visible here:
[image]

I tried to solve this issue with

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth=true]{tocline}{section}
```

but this makes every numbers width to the biggest numbers width and looks really not nice:
[image]

As you can see, the spacing for the first one is now incredulously long. I know that there's a reason the titles are all at the same start point, but it really doesn't matter in my case, cause the indices titles split the two chapters (visually) in the end anyways.
So is there any way to tell the table of contents to only adjust the width from a specific point?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,halfparskip, 11pt]{scrartcl}
%\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[dynnumwidth=true]{tocline}{section} %Uncomment to active adjustment
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Normal section}
\renewcommand\thesection{Appendix~\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\section{This is Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE produces a warning:

Class scrartcl Warning: You've used obsolete option `halfparskip`. Usage of this option indicates an old document and changes compatibility level using `parskip=half,version=first, enabledeprecatedfontcommands` that may result in further warnings. If you don't want this, you should simply replace option `halfparskip` by `parskip=half`.

To avoid the warning and the switch to `version=first` use **`parskip=half`**!

Options `a4paper` and `11pt` are default and option `pdftex` is not needed.

Do not redefine `\thesection`. Use `\appendix`. Afterwards redefine `\sectionformat` and `\sectionmarkformat` after `\appendix` and add `dynnumwidth` for section in TOC.

```latex
\appendix
\providecommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\newcommand{\entrywithprefixformat}[2]{#1\enskip#2}
\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}
\renewcommand{\sectionmarkformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
    entrynumberformat=\protect\entrywithprefixformat{\appendixname},
    dynnumwidth
  ]{tocline}{section}
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}% <- changed!!
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\providecommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\newcommand{\entrywithprefixformat}[2]{#1\enskip#2}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}{%
  \renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
  \renewcommand{\sectionmarkformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
      entrynumberformat=\protect\entrywithprefixformat{\appendixname},
      dynnumwidth
    ]{tocline}{section}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to define an own entry for sections in appendix.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}% <- changed!!
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\providecommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\newcommand{\entrywithprefixformat}[2]{#1\enskip#2}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level:=section,
  beforeskip:=section,
  indent:=section,
  numwidth:=section,
  dynnumwidth,
  entryformat=\usekomafont{sectionentry},
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefixformat{\appendixname}
]{tocline}{appendixsection}

\AddToHook{cmd/appendix/after}{%
  \renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
  \renewcommand{\sectionmarkformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\autodot\enskip}%
  \renewcommand{\addsectiontocentry}[2]{\addtocentrydefault{appendixsection}{#1}{#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\appendix
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: Regarding the width it worked. However it was just ignoring the reformating of the section name in my case. Printed "Anhang" (which was German), so there was probably some overriding happening. Therefore these to lines were enough:
```
\newcommand{\entrywithprefixformat}[2]{#1\enskip#2}
 \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
      entrynumberformat=\protect\entrywithprefixformat{\appendixname},
      dynnumwidth
    ]{tocline}{section}%
  }%
```
(Since I am also fine with the German equivalent of Appendix.)

Answer (score 0):

I have looked, briefly, at the `scrartcl` class and could not find how to do what you want. Unfortunately `scrartcl` does not like the `tocloft` package which provides all sorts of means of adjusting The ToC, LoF and LoT. Here it is with an `article` version of your MWE.

```
[![% tocappspaceprob.tex  SE 642491

%\documentclass\[pdftex,a4paper,halfparskip, 11pt\]{scrartcl}
\documentclass\[pdftex,a4paper,halfparskip, 11pt\]{article}
%\DeclareTOCStyleEntry\[dynnumwidth=true\]{tocline}{section} %Uncomment to active adjustment
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Normal section}
\renewcommand\thesection{Appendix~\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

%%%%% increase space for Appendix ToC numbers
\addtocontents{toc}{\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{5pc}}
\section{This is Appendix}
\end{document}][1]][1]
```

Perhaps you can find something in the `scrartcl` manual that enables you to change the number width of specific kinds of ToC entries.

[image]r.png